Why can it be that connectors do not cause reflections when they are short enough?
I've always followed the usual guidelines but I can't help but having this question at the back of my mind: it is generally acknowledged that if connectors are shorter than 1/20th of the wavelength of the highest frequency content desired, they are essentially transparent and do not cause reflections. A rule of thumb for digital signals is the bandwidth to use is 10 to 20 times the signal rate (though it would in reality depend on rising and falling edges). Why?
The reason for my question is that reflections are supposed to occur when the medium changes in characteristic impedance. So I would expect that any change will result in reflections, and the severity of those reflections would depend on the impedance jump, and the length of the wire upstream. The length of the new medium should not matter following this logic, except when considering the second change in medium at the exit but the other one would dominate anyway. Why is it not like that?
In practice, it seems to me I can pretty much use any connector I want for Ethernet 10Mbps or even 100Mbps including those that are not impedance controlled, regardless of the cables that form the circuit, and I find that extremely suspicious.

RJ45 isn't exactly an impedance controlled design.


The reason for my question is that reflections are supposed to occur when the medium changes in characteristic impedance. So I would expect that any change will result in reflections, and the severity of those reflections would depend on the impedance jump, and the length of the wire upstream. The length of the new medium should not matter following this logic, except when considering the second change in medium at the exit but the other one would dominate anyway.

You already said it: you have to consider the second impedance discontinuity at the "far side" of the mismatched section. When you do, and you work out the math, you find that its contribution isn't dominated by the "first" one. Actually, if we assume that loss is insignificant, and that the impedance returns to its original value, then the second discontinuity reflects just as much power as the first one, only with the opposite phase (since the impedances on either side of it are swapped). This holds true regardless of how far the mismatched section is from either end of the transmission line.
And from that it becomes apparent that if the distance between the two discontinuities is only a few degrees, the reflections will be close to 180° out of phase as seen from anywhere, and so they nearly cancel out.
When loss is significant, the math doesn't work out quite as cleanly, but significant loss helps eat up reflected power, so the result is no worse in terms of ISI.


The length of the new medium should not matter following this logic,
except when considering the second change in medium at the exit but
the other one would dominate anyway.

The length of the new medium sets the phase of the returning reflection from the second change. Sure, the first one dominates, but the second reflection could add constructively or destructively depending on the phase.
